Positive semi-definiteness of specified covariance matrix
I am working with model where the covariance matrix will be of the form
$$\boldsymbol\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix} \omega_1^2\boldsymbol C & \omega_1\omega_2\boldsymbol C\\
\omega_1\omega_2\boldsymbol C & \omega_2^2\boldsymbol C
\end{pmatrix},$$
where $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are scalar parameters to be estimated. $\boldsymbol C$ is itself a covariance matrix which can be specified to be positive semi-definite. Fitting this model will require inverting $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ so I need $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ to also be positive semi-definite.
Will this specification lead to a positive semi-definite covariance structure?

Aren't covariance matrices positive semi-definite by the very fact alone of being covariance matrices?

It will be positive semi-definite for all $\mathbf{C}$ if it is positive semidefinite when you put $\mathbf{C} = 1$.

$$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix} \omega_1^2\boldsymbol C & \omega_1\omega_2\boldsymbol C\\
\omega_1\omega_2\boldsymbol C & \omega_2^2\boldsymbol C
\end{pmatrix}=\pmatrix{\omega_1&0\\ 0&\omega_2}\pmatrix{C&C\\ C&C}\pmatrix{\omega_1&0\\ 0&\omega_2}$$
As the central matrix is not imvertible (the second half of its columns is identical to the first half), $\Sigma$ isn't invertible.

Hi, Jean Marie!

What if I were to add iid noise to the on-diagonal elements of $\boldsymbol\Sigma$? Something like  $$\boldsymbol\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix} \omega_1^2\boldsymbol C+\epsilon_1^2\mathcal I & \omega_1\omega_2\boldsymbol C\
\omega_1\omega_2\boldsymbol C & \omega_2^2\boldsymbol C+\epsilon_2^2 \mathcal I
\end{pmatrix}.$$
I can make this a separate post if preferred. Thank you!

If you set $\epsilon_k=\omega_k^2 \epsilon'_k$, you can do a factorization as I have done ;  in this case, the central matrix is in general invertible (though with a bad "condition number")

not invertible.  If $\omega_1 = 0$  the rank is the same as the rank of $C,$  half of what you want. Same if $ \omega_2=0$ instead.
When both nonzero,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} I & 0\\
- \frac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} I & I
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \omega_1^2\boldsymbol C & \omega_1\omega_2\boldsymbol C\\
\omega_1\omega_2\boldsymbol C & \omega_2^2\boldsymbol C
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} I & - \frac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} I\\
0  & I
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} \omega_1^2\boldsymbol C & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
again has rank the same as $C:$   the matrices with the $I$   elements are invertible, for either one just flip the minus sign to invert it.

Hi Will. I see we are on the same wavelength !

Your $\Sigma$ wil NEVER be invertible since for any $X$ we have $(w_2X^T,-w_1X^T)\Sigma=0.$
